# Unable to save or update postmeta for custom post type via action using save_post hook

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, save-post

I'm trying to update a custom field by hooking into the `save-post` action, but for reasons I can't figure out, it's not working.

The following function is placed in the theme's `functions.php`:

```
function save_address_meta() {

      $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );

      $address = $meta['address'];
      update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $address, 'test');
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_address_meta', 50 );
```

I've tried using `pre_post_update` as well, as I understand that `save_post` won't actually fire unless something, other than a custom field, is updated in the post - but no luck with this one either.

I've spent a few hours searching for solutions on stackexchange and various other sources online, but just not coming right. This is a dumbed-down version of the original code, but even in this basic state it doesn't appear to be working.

Basically, I'm trying to get the custom field in question, then update it with a string value.

If I `print_r` the `$meta` array, the custom field value appears in an array as follows:

```
 [address] => Array ( [0] => 50 Call Lane Leeds LS1 6DT United Kingdom )
```

I've also tried accessing this custom field in the function above using `$address = $meta['address'][0]`.
I can echo out the value of the key this way, but if I'm not mistaken, it's the key I'll need to reference in order for the string, in the 3rd argument, to update the value as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $address, 'test');` to `update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'address', 'test');`

Comment: This was the issue in my case, a simple "syntax" error.  
Do you know why using a string would work instead of a variable?

Comment: The second argument for `update_post_meta()` function is `meta_key` . In your case `meta_key` is `address`

Comment: However, As Nathan suggested, Its better to use some check (whether its a revision or autosave, or if is the same post type you need) to make sure your action is fired at the perfect time.

Answer (score 3):

The `save_post` hook will fire whenever WordPress saves a post to the database. This includes saving WP revisions which will have a different post ID than the actual post. It's more than likely you are getting and saving the post meta to a revision instead of to the actual post.

Also, the `save_post` hook passes a few variables when it fires, including the post ID, so you don't have to use the `get_the_ID()` function.

```
function wpse_261414_save_post( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
  //* Make sure this isn't a post revision
  if( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
    return;
  }
  $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id );
  $address = $meta[ 'address' ];
  update_post_meta( $post_id, $address, 'test' );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_261414_save_post', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: You are right about `save-post` and when it fires. Thanks for the tips, I've ditched the `get_the_ID()` function in favour of the `$post_id` variable passed by `save_post`. turns out it's not saving the post meta to a revision, but I've kept that conditional check in there anyway for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this;

```
function save_address_meta() {
    global $post;
    if($post->post_type == 'your-custom-post-type'){
        $address_field = 'test'; //Get your address field here                  
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'address', 'test');
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_address_meta' );
```

And you can get your field value elsewhere may be for example inside the loop as;

```
$address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'address', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had these symptoms, but it turned out to be a validation check behaving unexpectedly, namely:

```
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post') ) return;
```

This had been working (for several years), but a Wordpress update caused it to fail.

I amended it to also take the $post_id (as per the [documentation example here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/)):

```
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id) ) return;
```

and all was well. So in case this helps anyone else...